# Python: Stop Skript with Controls without losing data

Tags: python, database, user-controls, spyder, experimental-design

I have a python scientific script for calculating some kind of heat transfer and flow dynamics running in a loop. Each time it passes the loop it will print out some information about the status of the script. With this data, i can see while running if it is a feasible simulation or sometimes at a certain point it gets unfeasible.

Question is, how to stop the script without losing data? Because at the end of the whole simulation i will print out some graphs etc but i dont want to run the script until the end, when i already see. So what i need is some user interruption, like ctrl+c. I thought about try-catch this keyboard user interrupt and then goto end of simulation to plot graphs etc.

Btw i am working in Spyder.

Thanks for any suggestions or more sophisticated solutions, here a little code example:

```
while i<10000:
    calculated_data = i + i
    print(calculated_data)

plt.plot(i,calculated_data)
```

So usually i would need the 10k runs, but when i see at lets say at i=500 it becomes unfeasible, but dont want loose calculated data (calculated_data), i want a user interruption somehow. But i also dont want to ask the user every step.

Comment: you can store the calculated data somewhere. May be in sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
try:
    while i<10000:
        calculated_data = i + i
        print(calculated_data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    save_me(calculated_data)
    raise
```

Edit: You could perhaps use an [asynchronous signal](https://pymotw.com/3/signal/), especially in a unix environment, for example

```
was_interrupted = False

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    global was_interrupted
    was_interrupted = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)

for s in range(max_simulation):
    params = next_parameterset()
    while i < 10000:
        calculated_data = i + 1
        print(calculated_data)
        if was_interrupted:
            save_me(params, calculated_data)
            was_interrupted = False
            break
```

So when you see that the inner loop needs to be interrupted, you kill the program with SIGUSR1 and it resumes the outer loop. You can do it from the terminal or from another python program that reads user input and sends `os.kill()` signals to the computing process.

Comment: Yeah that was the only way I was thinking of but I thought there might be better option or even user defined shortcuts

Comment: Okay, aktually when rethinking it is not convenient for my application. I have actually two loops because the inner loop is running the scientific simulation and the outer loop runs this simulation several times with different parametersets. So i want to skip one of the inner loop runs but still have next runs unaffected.

Comment: something like wait for user input for like 5 seconds every 50 runs. so if user does not click "abort", it will just continue.